# Modifying value of 5th argument from MIPS to C

Tags: c, mips

Assuming you have a function in MIPs that is called from C like this:

```
extern int test(int *var1, int *var1, int *var3, int *var4, int *var5);
```

Is it possible in MIPS to increase the value of the pointer *var5 (in C: ++var5) and return it to C (not using the $v0, $v1 registers, they are used for something else)?

Comment: MIPs uses v0 as the return register, if you want to avoid using it it might be worth changing the function type to void, you can increment var5 in place with (*var5)++ if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: C is pass ny value, there is no way to change the *var5* passed by the caller. You have to change function signature (pointer to pointer as argument, or returning modified pointer as the normal return value) to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually use v0 for another returning value. I need to increase var5 inside the mips function. I'm new to mips, I tried this:  addiu t1, sp, 16 ; addiu t2, t1, INCREASE_POINTER_VALUE;  sw t2, 0(t1)  but the value of the pointer does not get modify. Not sure how else I can do it

Comment: Ok, thanks hyde. Then I could move var5 to any of the first 4 arguments and would get passed by reference?

Comment: The passing mechanism does not change with the position of the parameter (fortunately). In C, *all* is passed by value. If you want to modify something, pass a pointer to it and modify what is pointed by it. In C, this requires the use of the `*` operator. In MIPS, if a pointer is in a register, you must load the content of the pointer (with `lw`) in a reg, modify it and store it back (with `sw`). If the pointer is stored in the stack (5th arg), there is an extra `lw` to store the pointer in a register, but after that, the mechanism is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks Alain. Sorry I think I haven't explained myself correctly, I don't want to change the content the pointer is "pointing at", that I can do, I want to change the address of the pointer. In C that would be ++var5 and then the pointer would now point at the original address +(sizeof var5 type) while keeping the content those pointers point at unchanged.

Comment: nevermind, I was passing the first argument as pointer, instead of pointer to pointer... duh